# Generalize CentOS and Ubuntu server in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, centos

I want to generalize CentOS and Ubuntu server for a lab that is using VirtualBox as virtualization environment. The main objective of the process is:

1. To create a VM with basic OS and utilities configured
2. Use the VM as a Core OS and prepare other VMs using different hostnames, ip addresses and user names.

I tried using commands like sys-unconfig but that does not gives me the desired result or probably I am not aware of how to use it.

Comment: you want to generalize what? deployment? installation? patch fixing? backup? can you be more specific? Your question is quite broad as is.

Comment: I want to install the OS and specific packages once and then want to generalize it such that i can use it as a core image and prepare new vm's using the core image. i don't want to keep reinstalling OS and packages again n again for different vm's on the network.

Comment: In that case, please [edit] your question and clarify. Explain precisely what you need without relying on comparisons to Windows programs that most of us *nix geeks will have never heard of. You should also explain whether the hardware of the various machines will be identical, and anything else that might be relevant.

Comment: It would also be useful, seeing as you mentioned “vm’s” in your comment, to add to your question what virtualisation platform you are planning to use.

Comment: when you say "Core OS" it is easy to confuse what you are asking for with [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/) - a pre-existing product

Comment: http://capnjosh.com/blog/deploying-vm-clones-of-centos-6-6-in-virtualbox/

Comment: every `vm` software has a `clone` option. install base `OS`, shutdown `vm`, now clone it, fire the clone up, done. Or you can go old school and open a file explorer and navigate to folder containing `vm` files and use `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v`

Answer (score 0):

In vmware's world, what your are looking for is a **template**.

You manually create a vm, with proper packages, users, kernel settings and all.

Then you "template" it, and create other VM from this template.

There are still few trap and pitfall.

- you have to set IP manually (or use DHCP),
- you might have to change LAN's name (e.g. you interfaces might be eth2 and eth3 instead of eth0, eth1)

please note that this apply to fresh install. You cannot (with vmware's template at least) apply patchs and kernel value to an already installed and running VM.

Comment: AFAIK virtualbox does not support vmware templates.

Comment: @jordanm By the time I wrote this answer, there was no mention of virtualbox. I'll de deleting this answer soon.